# How can I set a variable to be equal to 0 if null or increment it if it is not null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I figured out this code which does half the job:

```
SELECT @SEQ = Isnull(@SEQ,0)
```

But how can I make this set the `@SEQ` to be incremented by one if it is not `null`?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't come up with:  `isnull(@Seq, -1) + 1`.  In any case Martin Smith and Mureinik have the shortest solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do

```
SELECT @SEQ = Isnull(@SEQ+1,0)
```

As adding 1 to null would still yield null.

Answer (score 4):

Incrementing a  `null` will result in `null`, so this can be accomplished with a `coalesce` expression:

```
SELECT @SEQ = COALESCE(@SEQ + 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` expression:

```
select @SEQ = case when @SEQ is null then 0 else @SEQ + 1 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way if you are using `Sql Server 2012+`. Use [**IIF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213574.aspx)

```
select @SEQ = IIF(@SEQ is null, 0, @SEQ + 1)
```